# .Error Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

conf.js

```
exports.config = {

    directConnect: true,

    framework: 'jasmine',
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['FirstTestcase.js'],

    asmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000
    },

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
      }

}
```

testcase.js

```
describe("my first test case",function(){
    it("execute test case",function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);    
        browser.get("");
            element(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
            element(By.id("tenant")).sendKeys("demo");
            element(By.id("continue")).click();
            element(By.id("password")).sendKeys("test");
            element(By.id("login")).click();
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);


    });
});
```

The problem im facing is . My Login page is not developed in angular js and once i login the applicaiton is angular js.

Once i click login on the code

i tried even

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        value = 0;
        done();
    }, 6000);
})
```

but nothing helps.

Can someone give solution?

Comment: maybe because you have `asmineNodeOpts` instead of `jasmineNodeOpts`?

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing - jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000 which is 20 sec  to jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000 which 
is 2 minute

Since you have jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000 in your config file, each of the block function = beforeAll, beforeEach, afterEach and afterAll and it() in your tests should be completed with in 20 sec individually  else the runner gets timeout error and displays error what you are getting.

Comment: Can you please let me know the reason for down voting the answer?